# Changing from ñ to � in file when pushed in git remote repository

Tags: git, git-bash

One of my colleague's branch changes the special characters such as ñ into � in sql files automatically when he pushed his changes to the remote branch. What's the cause of this and how can we fix this?

For context, the first picture is how it appears in his local repo and the second one is the what is pushed in the remote repo.

**Local**
[image]

**Remote**
[image]

Comment: I would doubt it's a remote-related problem. What will land in the remote _has to be_ what the revision contains.... at the binary level. Are you completely sure the file is saved correctly in the revision (leave the push operation on the side).

Comment: Are you talking about *file contents* or *file names* here?

Comment: Can you please give more information on what leads you to say "ñ are turned into �" ? Do you mean : your colleague observed that the file *on his disk* had its content modified ? or is it "when he opens his file in his editor he sees ñ" vs "when he views his file in the web GUI of the remote he sees �" ? or is it "on his machine he sees ñ" vs "after fetching his changes, on my machine I see �" ? or ...

Comment: I'm talking about file contents in a SQL file. The characters show perfectly normal in his local repository, but when he pushed the files, the lines with special characters appear in files changed with character replaced.

Comment: ok ; sorry for the annoying repetition, but : can you please describe where these � characters are displayed ? in a web browser ? in your IDE on your local machine ? ...

Comment: (on a less repetitive note ;) ) : on his machine, can you check the encoding of said file on his local machine ? is it UTF-8 ? a single byte encoding such as ISO 8859 or Windows 1252 ? or something else ?

Comment: I edited my post and added a sample snippet

Comment: What service hosts your remote ? gitlab ? github ?